# Getting duplicate records using mysql query

Tags: mysql

Am trying to get duplicate records in my table and its not working fully,

My table looks like this:

```
id  vehicle     dates
---------------------------
1   GKB301J     2016-04-02
2   GKB301J     2016-04-02
3   GKB301J     2016-04-03
4   GKB275F     2016-04-14
5   GKB275F     2016-04-05
6   GKB275F     2016-04-14
7   GKB275F     2016-04-13
8   GKB438F     2016-04-29
```

From the above table, i am expecting to get:

```
id  vehicle     dates
 1  GKB301J     2016-04-02
 2  GKB301J     2016-04-02
 4  GKB275F     2016-04-14
 6  GKB275F     2016-04-14
```

but my query is not working well:

below is how my code is:

```
SELECT j.id, j.vehicle, j.dates
FROM ISSUANCE j
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT dates, vehicle
    FROM ISSUANCE
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(dates, '%Y-%m-%d')
    HAVING COUNT(id) >= 2
) i ON DATE_FORMAT(j.dates, '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(i.dates, '%Y-%m-%d') AND j.vehicle = i.vehicle
WHERE j.dates BETWEEN '2016-04-01' AND '2016-04-30'
```

Comment: "It's not working" does not explain to us what is going wrong. You need to show us your expected output and your actual output.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using SELECT DISTINCT - that is supposed to return unique (non-duplicate) records.

Check out:
    https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: Doesn't OP *want* duplicates?

Comment: My database is too big, so I have to filter it out by date range. So if I use the count method. It might take even 3days to run since there is no range

Answer (score 0):

As your question tells you wanna get duplicate :

```
select vehicle , dates from Issuance WHERE dates BETWEEN '2016-04-01' AND '2016-04-30'
minus
(select vehicle , dates, count(*) from Issuance 
WHERE dates BETWEEN '2016-04-01' AND '2016-04-30'
group by vehicle , dates having count(*) = 1);
```

Comment: This is not bringing the duplicated in the range of dates selected

Comment: i thought you could add date to yourself , anyway i have edited